# The Arev Symbol of Fraction

Tags: symbols, arev

Excuse me.

I have used \usepackage{arev} to reproduce Arev font in \LaTeX.  But, the root-square symbol and the fraction symbol are still thin, not bold, and still in Roman form.

[image: Square-Root Symbol]

[image: Fraction Symbol]

How to change the square-root symbol and the fraction symbol to be same form of Arev font?

```
\documentclass[12pt,openany]{buku2}


\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[left=2.3cm,right=2.3cm,top=3.0cm,bottom=2.0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\geometry{papersize={8.5in,11.75in}}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{amscd}
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{euscript}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{makeidx}

%\usepackage{mathptmx}
%\usepackage{times}
%\usepackage{txfonts}

\usepackage{arev}
%\usepackage{cmbright}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}

\newcommand{\nn} {\nonumber}
\newcommand{\E} {\mathcal{E}}
\newcommand{\LL} {\mathcal{L}}
\newcommand{\ve} {\overrightarrow}
\newcommand{\ten} {\overleftrightarrow}
\newcommand{\awalbukti}{\begin{proof}[Bukti]}
\newcommand{\awaljawab}{\begin{proof}[Jawaban]}
\newcommand{\akhirbukti}{\end{proof}}
\newcommand{\akhirjawab}{\end{proof}}



\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{soal}{Soal}[section]



\input{daftar_penggalan_kata}


%\makeindex


\begin{document}




\begin{titlepage}
\title{\Huge \textbf{Mekanika Klasik Analitik}
\vspace{0.75cm}
%\begin{figure}[h]
%   \centering
%       \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{gambar_sampul.jpg}
%   \label{fig:gambar}
%\end{figure}
}
\author{\LARGE \textbf{R. Tao R. H. \& C. M. G. Leditto}}
\maketitle
\end{titlepage}

\pagebreak
\



\input{kata_pengantar}


\tableofcontents




\section{Notasi Turunan Parsial}

Andaikan $x$, $y$, $z$, $u$, dan $v$ adalah peubah-peubah riil.  Notasi seperti $(\partial z/\partial y)_x$ berarti bahwa $z\mapsto(x,y)$ diturunkan terhadap $y$ dengan menganggap $x$ konstan.
%
Andaikan selain itu, $(x,y)\mapsto(u,v)$, maka bolehlah $z = z_{x,y}(x,y_{u,v}(u,v_{x,u}(x,u)))$, sehingga
\begin{eqnarray}
\left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\right)_u = \left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\right)_y + \left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\right)_x \left(\frac{\partial y}{\partial v}\right)_u \left(\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}\right)_u.
\label{201808160554}
\end{eqnarray}
%
Kita dapat menuliskan $y = y_{u,v}(u,v_{x,u}(x,u))$, sehingga
\begin{eqnarray}
\left(\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}\right)_u = \left(\frac{\partial y}{\partial v}\right)_u \left(\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}\right)_u.
\label{201808160553}
\end{eqnarray}
%
Dari persamaan (\ref{201808160553}), maka persamaan (\ref{201808160554}) menjadi
\begin{equation}
\left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\right)_u = \left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\right)_y + \left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\right)_x \left(\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}\right)_u.
\label{201808160556}
\end{equation}
%
Pada persamaan (\ref{201808160556}), tampak bahwa secara umum,
\begin{equation}
\left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\right)_u \neq \left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\right)_y.
\end{equation}


\printindex

\end{document}
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us a short compilable tex code resulting in your showed screenshot!

Comment: [![The My LaTeX Code][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LqVGS.png

Comment: Please post an actual code in your question (rather than posting a screen shot of a code in the comments).

Comment: We do not have your `\input`ed files ... Can you please delete in your code `\input{isi_buku_ini}` and add instead the short tex code building the content of your screenshot?

Comment: Link of buku2.cls is http://kamp.scienceontheweb.net/buku2.cls